# Specifying a Functional Dependency for a Relation (Determining S2 follows from S1)

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

So I have this question and I was wondering why `S2 = {AD->C}` follows from S1.

Consider the relation R(A,B,C,D,E) and the set of functional dependencies S1 = {AB → C, AE → D, D → B}. Which of the following sets S2 of FDs does **NOT** follow from S1?

```
S2 = {AD->C}
S2 = {AD->C, AE->B}
S2 = {ABC->D, D->B}  //correct answer 
S2 = {ADE->BC}
```

So by using the FD in S1, and applying closure:

```
{AD}+ = {ABCD}   //why does this set follow from S1? What about E?
{AD}+ = {ABCD}, {AE}+ = {ABCDE} 
{ABC}+ = {ABC}, {D}+ = {B} //correct answer
{ADE}+ = {ABCDE}
```

Comment: AB→C implies ABD→C. D→B therefore ABD→C implies AD→C, AD→B.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the result of the closure to contain all the attributes. As long as the closure you get contains all the attributes on the right-hand side of S2, then S2 follows from S1.

In this case after you did the closure, C is in the closure which means S2 follows from S1